# ForkJoin 2 BehaviorSubjects

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

I have two behaviour subject streams what I'm trying to forkJoin with no luck.
As I imagined it gives back the two last values of it. Is this possible to implement it somehow?

It is not called after the subject.

```
let stream1 = new BehaviorSubject(2);
let stream2 = new BehaviorSubject('two');

Observable.forkJoin(stream1, stream2)
    .subscribe(r => {
         console.log(r);
    });
```

Answer (score 26):

Maybe you want to use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) instead of `forkJoin`, it's useful if you don't want to wait for a `complete()` call.

With [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest), when any source observable (in your case, your behavior subjects) emits a value, [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) will trigger:

```
const stream1 = new BehaviorSubject(2);
const stream2 = new BehaviorSubject('two');

combineLatest(stream1, stream2)
    .subscribe(r => {
         console.log(r);
    });

stream1.next(3);
stream2.next('three');
```

Console log:

> (2) [2, "two"] // initial state
>
> (2) [3, "two"] // next triggered on stream1
>
> (2) [3, "three"] // next triggered on stream2

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qzxo3n

Answer (score 24):

Note what [`forkJoin()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) actually does from its documentation:

> Wait for Observables to complete and then combine last values they emitted.

This means that `forkJoin()` emits a value when **all input Observable** are complete. When using `BehaviorSubject` this means explicitly calling `complete()` on both of them:

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

const stream1 = new BehaviorSubject(2);
const stream2 = new BehaviorSubject('two');

forkJoin(stream1, stream2)
  .subscribe(r => {
    console.log(r);
  });

stream1.complete();
stream2.complete();
```

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-9nqtx6

March 2019: Updated for RxJS 6.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Have you tested your code, because the log is not invoked in my computer?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `take(1)` pipe or `complete()` method that mentioned above.

```
private subjectStream1 = new BehaviorSubject(null);
stream1$: Observable = this.subjectStream1.asObservable();

private subjectStream2 = new BehaviorSubject(null);
stream2$: Observable = this.subjectStream2.asObservable();

forkJoin({
  stream1: this.stream1$.pipe(take(1)),
  stream2: this.stream2$.pipe(take(1))
})
.pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed$))
.subscribe(values) => console.log(values));
```