# Rather Complex RXJS Observable never completing

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm creating an RXJS observable to perform a task given an input of an array of URLs:

```
let scrapeObservable: Observable<IProduct> = Observable.from(urlList)
  .mergeMap(url => Observable.forkJoin(
    Observable.of(url),
    getPageDom(url), // Returns Observable that completes with PageDom
    getExtractionRule(parseURL(url)["Host"]) // returns observable with data needed to perform work on the page dom
  ).delay(timeDelay += intervalTime)) // scrapes one url every set interval - using 0 in this case
  .mergeMap(result => getProductInfoFromDOMObservable(result[0], result[1], result[2][0], result[2][1], requiredFields)) // performs work on page dom using data above.
  .merge(maxConcurrentRequests) // prevents more than an certain number of processes from taking place simultaneously.
  .catch(handleError);
```

When I subscribe to this observable it appears as though for some inputs (rather large lists of URLs >500) it never calls complete or error.  It's like the observable just hangs.  I can't figure out why this is happening but it is causing problems with my code.  For small inputs it works correctly, and it doesn't always fail for large inputs, just some of the time.

Any ideas on what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: then you have a problem with pagedom or else but probably not with rxjs. So trace that instead

Comment: Have a look at one of these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809658/observable-forkjoin-not-firing/42809962#42809962 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722440/forkjoin-2-behaviorsubjects/39727134#39727134 I guess you have the same problem here

Comment: @user3743222 Thanks to both of you! I traced my problem down and it was within my getPageDom function.