# .asObservable dont want to work with Observable.forkJoin

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, fork-join

I have service:

```
export class ConfigService {
  private _config: BehaviorSubject<object> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public config: Observable<object> = this._config.asObservable();

  constructor(private api: APIService) {
    this.loadConfigs();
  }

  loadConfigs() {
   this.api.get('/configs').subscribe( res => this._config.next(res) );
  }
}
```

---

Trying to call this from component:

```
...
Observable.forkJoin([someService.config])
  .subscribe( res => console.log(res) ) //not working 

someService.config.subscribe( res => console.log(res) ) // working
...
```

How can i use `Observable.forkJoin` with `Observable` variable `config`?

I need to store configs in service and wait unlit them and others request not finished to stop loader.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using `BehaviorSubject` you should know that you can call `next()` and `complete()` manually.

The `forkJoin()` operator emits only when all of its source Observables have emitted at least one values **and** they all completed. Since you're using a Subject and the `asObservable` method the source Observable never completes and thus the `forkJoin` operator never emits anything.

Btw, it doesn't make much sense to use `forkJoin` with just one source Observable. Also maybe have a look at `zip()` or `combineLatest()` operators that are similar and maybe it's what you need.

Two very similar question:

- [Observable forkJoin not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809658/observable-forkjoin-not-firing/42809962#42809962)
- [ForkJoin 2 BehaviorSubjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722440/forkjoin-2-behaviorsubjects/39727134#39727134)

Comment: tywm for answer

Comment: @martin: `combineLatest()` was what I needed exactly. thanks a bunch.