# Subscribing to data within JS Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, observable

I am trying to change the center of a map within a dynamic script. The issue is that I do get the data that I am subscribing to, but it does not change the center of the map. I tested this out by creating a setInterval() within the component and seeing if the data changes, after I execute the method outside the component. Here is an example of the code

https://codesandbox.io/s/joey-basic-gmaps-lw5d4

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  public markerLat = 39;
  public markerLng = -76;
  title = "CodeSandbox";
  private apiKey = environment.googleMapsAPIkey;

  constructor(private data: DataService) {
    const dynamicScripts = [
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + this.apiKey
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < dynamicScripts.length; i++) {
      const node = document.createElement("script");
      node.src = dynamicScripts[i];
      node.type = "text/javascript";
      node.async = true;
      node.charset = "utf-8";
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(node);
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.markerLat.subscribe(markerLat => this.markerLat = markerLat);
    this.data.markerLng.subscribe(markerLng => this.markerLng = markerLng);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.initMap();
    }, 1000);
  }
  ngOnChanges() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.initMap();
    }, 1000);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.data.markerLat.subscribe(markerLat => this.markerLat = markerLat).unsubscribe();
    this.data.markerLng.subscribe(markerLng => this.markerLng = markerLng).unsubscribe();
  }
  initMap() {
    const google = window.google;

    const center = { lat: this.markerLat, lng: this.markerLng };
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: center
    });
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: center, map: map });
  }
}
```

Comment: @Chellappanவ the market is visible... it just does not change positions

Comment: move you  initMap method inside subscribe method

Comment: @Chellappanவ I do not know exactly what u mean by that... can you show me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting data from asyn source the excution order of initMap will differ. Move your initMap method inside subscribe block. Use forkJoin to get lat and lng observable to get complete first.

**Try this**

```
    import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

    export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    ngOnInit() {
       const latLng = forkJoin(
       this.data.markerLat,
       this.data.markerLng
       ).subscribe(([markerLat, markerLng])=>{
        this.markerLat = markerLat;
        this.markerLng = markerLng;
        this.initMap();
     })
   }
 }
```

Comment: I see what you are doing here and it makes sense... however the map has failed to load and I get no error from the console

Comment: can you console inside subcribe method and see wheather you getting data or not?

Comment: It does not console anything... I don't think it reaches the method at all

Comment: you have to complete the observable to get value : https://codesandbox.io/s/joey-basic-gmaps-tf9h7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Check this for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722440/forkjoin-2-behaviorsubjects

Comment: So the issue is that I get the data but the map still does not change... check the codesandbox for the update

Comment: Did you see the console it throwing no API key error?

Comment: yes I removed mine from the environment.ts... do you have one?

Comment: do you see the issue?

Comment: can you change the location with the input boxes?

Comment: Can't you use setcenter method to change the center of the coordinate after map gets initialised

Comment: If yiu call initMap again and again it will create new instances everytime it's call.Instead of that you can create map once and use that instance to change center

Comment: the issue is that in my actual project I am doing this from a parent component, not the javascipt itself... I might have to think about this a little

Comment: You can get map instance using viewchild from parent component